# TFIDVECTORIZER: All texts are stopwords causing error

Tags: stop-words, tfidfvectorizer

Im running this code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

def lemmatizer(text):
    return [word.lemma_ for word in nlp(text)]

# we need to generate the lemmas of the stop words
stop_words_str = " ".join(STOP_WORDS) # nlp function needs a string
stop_words_lemma = set(word.lemma_ for word in nlp(stop_words_str))

tfidf_lemma = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=100, 
                              stop_words=stop_words_lemma.union({"pax", "west", "hyatt", "wscc","borderlands"}),
                                tokenizer=lemmatizer)

tfidf_lemma.fit(documents)
print(tfidf_lemma.get_feature_names())
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string.
```

I suspect this is because some of the responses I'm dealing with are purely made of stopwords. Im using stopwords from Spacy.

```
from spacy.lang.en import STOP_WORDS
```

I've read some of the responses and there are some like "there's something for everyone" which I believe when filtered with stopwords turns to NaN causing the error. Any good fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Twas a stupid question. I actually made an error in my data preparation and missed the NaN values in `documents` because I forgot to use `.dropna()` before converting the dataframe column to list.